# Can an Imbalanced Datset be an oportunity for Transfer Learning with Neural Networks?

Tags: neural-network, loss-function, imbalanced-data

While solving classification tasks on imbalanced datasets with  Neural Networks(NN) there are two general ways of handling imbalanced data:

A. Resample the data, either with over or undersampling until it's balanced.

B. Compute a weight per sample, to weigh the losses according to the class occurrence.

I thought about a third way, that might be possible:

C. Train and Autoencoder on all the input data, and use its encoding part, first layers for the actual Classifier. This way, the information in the majority classes would not be thrown away (as in A). Nor would every sample need to put through the actual Classifier while training (as in B), potentially saving computational costs.

Has anyone had any experience with this kind of approach or knows a publication regarding this?

To follow up on Dave's comment:
I have an imbalanced dataset that had too high Accuracy (0.90) compared to Precision (never over 0.2) and Recall (never over 0.2). Balancing the Dataset with undersampling did the trick and got the Precision and Recall up, at the loss of accuracy. This model should predict several stages of illness (non-binary classification?) as an aid for practitioners, where a False Positive is considered less harmful than a False Negative.

Comment: Statisticians do not see class imbalance as a problem, and there is no need to use undersampling, oversampling, artificial balancing, weighting, or transfer learning to solve a non-problem. It might be helpful if you said why you find the imbalance problematic.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Comment: Regarding your edit: what’s the problem?

Comment: You also can get an awesome detection rate at the expense of accuracy by diagnosing everyone with the disease. In fact, that will do away with those especially “harmful” false negatives, so why rebalance the data and get inferior performance to such a plan? // You will learn a lot by reading those first three links.

Comment: I am reading them, and already learned a lot.